# Clear the textbox with JS

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

This is my problem I created a textbox to check U.S cellphone number and a function in JS that check numbers only. the problem is after I enter wrong number and I want to clear the textbox the function in JS won't let me.

This my code:

```
function NumbersOnly(sender, args) {
    var text = sender.get_value() + args.get_keyCharacter();
    if (!text.match('^[0-9]+$') && text != '\b' && text != '(' && text != ')' && text != '-') {
        args.set_cancel(true);
    }
}
```

Cell:

```
            </td>
            <td style="text-align: left">
            <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtPhone" runat="server" MaxLength="25" Width="200px"><ClientEvents OnKeyPress="NumbersOnly"></ClientEvents></telerik:RadTextBox>                
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" ID="revPhone"
                            ControlToValidate="txtPhone"
                            Display="None"
                            ValidationExpression="^(\([0-9]{3}\) |[0-9]{3}-)[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$"
                            ValidationGroup="validateEditUser"
                            EnableClientScript="false"
                            ErrorMessage="- Please enter a valid phone number:(ex.) <b>(xxx-xxx-xxxx)</b></br>" />
        </tr>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just set `this.value=''` to clear its value in the function.

or in your case `sender.set_value('')` should also work

Comment: sorry but if I'm paste what u wrote after this line args.set_cancel(true);
It won't work on firefox why??? and when I click on star in the keyboard it deleting everything why is that????

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to jQuery, you could use `$('#txtPhone').val('');` to clear your textbox. This would also help with any cross-browser inconsistencies.

That's assuming the ID of the actual input element is **txtPhone** and not a mangled ID generated by webforms. If my memory serves correct, the RadTextBox control has a **CssClass** attribute which lets you set a CSS class for the rendered input field which you could also use.